# PHP Boolean error (T_BOOLEAN_OR)

Tags: php

Anything wrong with this code in terms of syntaxes

```
    $i=0;
while ($r=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))||($a=$sth_temp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $i++;
  $itemcount=countitemsofuser($r['id']);
  echo "\n<tr>";
  echo "<td><a class='editid' href='$scriptname?action=editsoftware&amp;id=".$r['id']."'>{$r['id']}</a></td>\n";
  echo "<td>{$r['manufacturerid']}</td>\n";
  echo "<td>{$r['stitle']}</td>\n";
  echo "<td>{$r['sversion']}</td>\n";
  echo "<td>{$a['stype']}</td>\n";
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: "Anything wrong with this code in terms of syntaxes".For that you have to execute the code and check any syntax error is there.

Comment: An IDE may help with this kind of errors

Comment: @Lame-up-duck: There's more going on: it's the assumption that OR conditions aren't short-circuited that is the real issue here. Agreed, it's not the OP's question, but once the syntax error is fixed, the next question the OP is likely to post will be about why `$a` is never assigned anything

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I agree.

Answer (score 2):

you have one closing `)` too many:

```
while ($r=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))||($a=$sth_temp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                   //here
```

It should be:

```
while ($r=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)||($a=$sth_temp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Even so, this code isn't quite what I'd call *good code*. You're fetching data from either one of two statements, not both satements at the same time... *never* both, in fact, owing to PHP short-circuiting your `while` condition. Lets replace `while` with if:

```
if ($r = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) || $a = $sth_temp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    //if fetched, $r is truthy, and this branch will be executed
   //    the second expression (right of the || operator) need never be evaluated
```

because of short-circuit evaluation, PHP will not execute the second expression (`$a = ...`) when the first condition evaluates to true.
If the first fetch call is truthy, the while-loop condition is true, simply because that's what *or* means: *if this or that is true*. There's no point in evaluating the second expression, the result of the condition is a given: it's true.

So, essentially, the loop will run through all result-sets of `$sth->fetch()`, and once there aren't any left to fetch there, that's when `$sth_temp->fetch` will be called. You could've written this:

```
while($r = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    //process $r
}
while(false || $a = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{//the false is what $sth->fetch() would be after a while in your code
    //process $a
}
```

Not what you want, is it. Even so: because you used the `||` operator, you acknowledge the possibility that, in some cases either one of the 2 fetch calls you're executing might fail, yet *inside* the while-loop, you simply assume for both `$a` and `$r` to be assigned associative arrays:

```
$itemcount=countitemsofuser($r['id']);
//...
echo "<td>{$a['stype']}</td>\n";
```

That's just all shades of wrong. If you want to process the data at the same time, either use `&&`:

```
while($r = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) && $a = $sth_temp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
}
```

To avoid the problems with short-circuit evaluation. Still, the moment one of these fetch calls returns false, you'll have to process the remainder of the data like this:

```
$leftRow = $a ? $a : $r;//get the fetched data from the resultset that isn't empty
$left = ($a ? $sth_temp : ($r ? $sth : false));//get the object on which to fetch
if ($left)
{//if there are some left:
    do
    {//begin with row that was already fetched
        //process $leftRow
    } while($leftRow = $left->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));//and keep fetching
}
```

But that's just awful, isn't it.
It's far more likely that you can solve this problem easily and *much* more efficiently by altering your query, to use a JOIN for example...

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. You taught me a lot. I'll go through couple of tutorials to get the hang of it.

Comment: @Carter: [found the section in the help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that asks you _not_ to comment saying _"thanks"_. The question I linked to goes into great detail on the why's and how's